# Writing Regex for multiple patterns

Tags: regex

I am extremely new to regex and have to implement in for a final project in my grad school curricula. I have to read last login info on unix which can contain various record types such as

Here is an example of one of the lines that I have to match. I am trying to figure out what is the best way of matching each of the individual items in the output. There is a username, terminal, start date time, start date end time, duration and host. I am looking for tips on the most efficient way to match multiple lines such as the one below.

fraziered pts/50       Thu Oct 27 09:02:38 2016 - Thu Oct 27 10:05:10 2016  (01:02)    rnh49119.etsu.edu

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I have tried going item by item in the line of text. For example creating a regex for username then for terminal etc. I plan on piecing it all together at the end using python when I read the file line by line. Is it best practice to do it this way or would a better way be writing one big regex?